# Passing parameters to decorator at runtime

Tags: python

If I create a python decorator function like this

```
def retry_until_true(tries, delay=60):
    """
    Decorator to rety a function or method until it returns True.
    """
    def deco_retry(f):
        def f_retry(*args, **kwargs):
            mtries  = tries
            rv = f(*args, **kwargs)
            while mtries > 0:
                if rv is True:
                    return True
                mtries -= 1
                time.sleep(delay)
                rv = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return False
        return f_retry
    return deco_retry
```

I can use it like this

```
    @retry_until_true(20, delay=30)
    def check_something_function(x, y):
        ...
        return True
```

But is there a way to pass different values for 'tries' and 'delay' to the decorator at runtime, so that 20 and 30 are variables?

Comment: The decorator is called at def time.  If you want to pass different values at runtime why not just have a function. E.g.: `def retry_until_true(func, tries, delay):...`.

Answer (score 15):

Sure you can, just nest your function definition in another function, for example:

```
def explicit_setup_func(tries, delay=60):
    @retry_until_true(tries, delay)
    def check_something_function(x, y):
        # Code
```

However, the class decorator solution is more practical.

Comment: A very important point is that **this approach works without modifying the decorator functions, so it can be used with library decorators as well**. So it is more general

Answer (score 12):

You can use a class as a decorator, with instance variables for `tries` and `delay`:

```
class RetryUntilTrue(object):
    def __init__(self, f=None, tries=10, delay=30):
        self.f = f
        self.tries = tries
        self.delay = delay

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.f is None:
            self.f = args[0]
        else:
            tries = self.tries
            while tries:
                if self.f(*args, **kwargs):
                    return True

                tries -= 1
                time.sleep(self.delay)
```

Usage:

```
@RetryUntilTrue
def foo(x):
    pass

foo.tries = 20
foo.delay = 1

@RetryUntilTrue(tries=100, delay=9999)
def bar(x):
    pass

bar.tries -= 1
bar.delay = foo.delay
```

Comment: That's great but @RetryUntilTrue(tries=100, delay=9999) throws error