# How to pass parameters to decorators at run-time?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am using decorators to do some context management like file backup, restore sorts in my project and trying to use decorators for that purpose.

But i dont understand how to pass the argument to the decorator at run time.

For example my class would look like:

```
class myLogFileHandler:
    def __init__(self,file):
        self.file=file
        return

    @copyAndRestoreFile(file=<how-pass-self.file-here?>)
    def performAction(**kwargs):
        """
           do something
        """
```

And my decorator would be:

```
def copyAndRestoreFile(file):
    def dec(fn):
        def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
            #copy file to temp...
            fn(*args,**kwargs)
            #restore file from temp...
        return wrapper
    return dec
```

But as you see the file Name will be availble only when i create an object. So how to solve such issues.

I tried couple of solutions which worked:

1. Make the decorator without any arguments and make it look for a particular variable in the input args dictionary..

   ```
   def copyAndRestoreFile(fn):
       def dec(**kwargs,file):
           #copy file to temp...
           fn(*args,**kwargs)
           #restore file from temp...
       return dec  

   @copyAndRestoreFile
   def performAction(**kwargs,file=self.file):
       """
          do something
       """
   ```

   With this approach i cant make the decorator a generic one which can be used by any one.. Any one who uses it should have a file arg to the function that is decorated.. that is the con that i am seeing...
2. Decorate at run-time..

   ```
   def performAction(**kwargs):
       copyAndRestoreFile(file=self.file)(self._actualActionCode)(**kwargs)

   def _actualActionCode(**kwargs):
       """
          do something
       """
   ```

Are there any better ways to approach the problem?

Comment: One way would be to change `def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):` to `def wrapper(self, *args,**kwargs):` and use the `self` argument to resolve your filename. This will however make your decorator only usable in conjunction with your specific class.

Comment: yes i agree.. if some other class stores the filename in some other attribute name then it wont work .. :(

Comment: The second example can also be achieved in the `__init__` with `self.performAction = copyAndRestoreFile(file=self.file)(self._actualActionCode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example please see here - [Passing parameters to decorator at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855418/passing-parameters-to-decorator-at-runtime)

If there are other details please clarify.